# Window.print() is running before window.location.replace

Tags: javascript

My current code is trying to redirect to a page with a more printable version of the information, I am using window.location.replace to replace the page with the print friendly page then using window.print() to print it off, however it comes up with the print prompt before it replaces the page and tries to print the previous page. Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

```
function btnIncidentPrint(id)
{
window.location.replace('<c:url value="/print/?objtype=INCIDENT&type=INCIDENT&id="/>'+id);
window.print();
}
```

Comment: That's not a valid URL.

Comment: If you replace the URL, the page reloads, and scripts on the current page stop running.

Comment: the replace method takes a url. You passed it something else. Instead, create a print stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser may not immediately respond to `window.location` changes; there may be a delay.

But once it *has* responded to the `window.location` change, it will no longer run any of your code, so you won't be able to `window.print()` any more!

One solution is to put the print-friendly view in another window or frame, and call `.print()` on that window instead of the one you're replacing. You could immediately remove the frame so it isn't cluttering up the page.

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.onload = function() {
  iframe.contentWindow.print();
  iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
};
iframe.src = '?view=print';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: As pointed out a print popup or print style sheets are your only options

Comment: Thank you this seemed to work like how I wanted it, I will have to do more testing when I have printer access but this appears to work correctly!